# How can I find out the number of outputs returned by a python function?

Tags: python, function, output, abstract-syntax-tree

Imagine there are two Python functions:

```
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return x,x**2
```

I would like to find out how many outputs are returned by `f1` and how many outputs are returned by `f2`.

I would like to avoid the following solution:

```
result = f1(1)
no_outputs = len(result) if type(result) == tuple else 1
```

Since this solution fails when a function returns a tuple.

I started playing around with the python `ast` (abstract syntax tree) library, and was wondering if there was any way to parse the syntax tree for a function to figure out the number of outputs returned?

Something along the lines of:

```
import inspect
import ast

src = inspect.getsourcelines(f1)[0]

string = ''.join(src)
ast_   = ast.parse(string)
```

I explored `ast_` but am not able to find what the returns are.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Since `f1` is hard-coded, just look at its documentation to see what it returns.

Comment: I am writing some code that will behave according to the number of outputs a function `f` returns. Unfortunately, I cannot change the way `f` works and standardize it's output (which is the right thing to do), for complicated reasons :)

Comment: For `f1` and `f2` what is your expected output for this question?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im for f1 the output is 1, and for f2 the output is 2

Comment: @chepner I do not know in advance what the function will be. I can however get the source lines for the function and look for the return statement and count the number of commas (but this doesn't sound like a good solution to me)

Comment: @kyphos Why you cannot simply use the `len` function?

Comment: @nbro if there is a function that returns a list or a tuple, then using len does not give me the number of outputs but the length of one output that happens to be a list or tuple

Comment: I don't see any necessity to calculate the number of return values, since you should know in advance the number...

Comment: What about a function which has multiple `return` statements? Typically these are called when different conditionals are met. If they have different lengths, how do you get the length without calling it with some arguments (to see which conditional path is taken).

Comment: Python is dynamically typed. This does not mean it's magical and that you can return whatever values you want...

Comment: If you explain exactly for what you need to know this, maybe someone can come out with alternatives or stuff like that...

Comment: @Ffisegydd very good point! Let's assume the functions I will be inspecting only has 1 return statement.

Comment: @nbro, I do not know which functions I will be be inspecting so I don't know the number of return values in advance. Basically I have a chain of functions that transforms data. Each function in this chain will either produce 2 results or 1 result. The next function in the chain should then take as input the results from the previous function.

Comment: Why not just accept `*args` in your functions then? And then once you've gotten the `args` tuple, do `if len(args == 1:` etc.

Comment: @Ffisegydd a lot of the functions are imported, I could write a wrapper for them, hmm that might work

Comment: Imagine `y = f1(f2(x))` call. `y` here is both f1's returned value and f2's returned value (because `f1` returns its argument) i.e., both functions return *the exact same object* in this case despite appearing to return different number of values in the source.

Answer (score 6):

Technically a function returns ONE value.  That one value might be a tuple, a dictionary, or any arbitrarily complex object (including collection objects).

The appearance of multiple return values is merely the result of some syntactic sugar around automatic unpacking and the fact that the tuple operator in Python is actually the , (the comma; the parentheses are not necessary in a *return* statement and only required in cases where the , (comma) would be ambiguous).

Because Python is dynamically typed a function can return different types of values (objects) depending on its arguments or on the program's global state when it's called.  It can return different types of objects for different calls during the same program (interpreter/VM) session.

You should consider the return type of a function to be a matter of documentation ... any well written Python function will document its return type (preferably in the doc string).

It is fairly common for methods of classes that are wrapped around some data structure to *return **self*** ... which allows for a "chained usage" pattern:  *Foo.fiddle().faddle().spritz().output()* ... where we perform a whole series of operations on the object all in a single, concise expression.

Comment: Thanks, this was very enlightening!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comments that this is a somewhat curious question... However, to answer your question following the approach you propose, let's start with the following simplifying assumptions:

1. There is only one return statement, which occurs at the very end
   of each function
2. Commas can be used to determine the "number of outputs", i.e.
   `(x, 2)` and `x, 2` are both considered to be two "outputs"
3. Following from point 2, return statements are comprised of a series of variables (possibly as lists or tuples), and never more complicated expressions like generators or list comprehensions

We assume the above because otherwise you would almost certainly need to properly parse the subset of valid Python code, e.g. by building an AST. Given the above, you take the last string from the list returned by `inspect.getsourcelines()` and match a regular expression:

```
In [47]: def f2(x):
   ....:     return x, x**2

In [48]: ret2 = inspect.getsourcelines(f2)

In [49]: ret2
Out[49]: ([u'def f2(x):\n', u'    return x, x**2\n'], 1)

In [55]: ret_pattern = r'return\s*(.*)\n*$'

In [56]: out2 = re.findall(ret_pattern, ret2[0][-1])

In [57]: out2
Out[57]: [u'x, x**2']

In [58]: len(out2[0].split(','))
Out[58]: 2
```

Testing with returning a tuple of variables:

```
In [59]: def f3(x):
   ....:     return (x, x**2, x**3)
   ....:

In [62]: out3 = re.findall(ret_pattern, inspect.getsourcelines(f3)[0][-1])

In [63]: len(out3[0].split(','))
Out[63]: 3
```

Comment: There can be multiple return statements in the definition of a function.  The value returned will be determined by the first one that's encountered by the flow of control.  There is only a single return value ... it can be a container.  If you have a statement like return a,b then Python implicitly instantiates a tuple and packs the objects bound to a and b into that.

Comment: Incidentally you can return the results from complex expressions and you can return generators from functions.  Generators like functions are first class objects and can be passed as arguments, bound to names (variables) or returned from functions and method just like any other object.

Comment: Agreed, hence the simplifying assumptions :)

Comment: I'm not advocating doing any of the above -- as other comments have pointed out, there are almost certainly better ways to go about solving the OP's problem. From a fundamental / philosophical perspective, the answer I've suggested is rather silly.